# HTML intellisense not working in VSC

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm try to get intellisense for html in vsc.

when I create a index.html file, there's no intellisense for any tags.

but if I rename the file to index.htm, then I have the intellisense for html

also, my extensions like "auto close tags", "react sinippets ", they both not working under .html extension.

I've checked my settings for html, I don't find anything wrong.

but my icon extension works, the icon shows it is a html file, but intellisense and extensions related to html are not working

what cloud be the problem of this ? is there anything conflict in my extension or there's some setting issue I'm not aware about ?

Thanks !

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the `code --disable-extensions` command in the terminal and then restart your Visual Studio Code. 
For me, it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to Extensions Section

2 - Click on the menu (**3 dots** in top right corner)

3 - Click **Disable all installed extensions**

4 - Reload VS Code

5 - Go again to the menu in Extensions Section and click on **Enable All Extensions**

Hopefully that will works